# Unexpected issue with method overriding

Tags: java

My issue is something similar to this

```
public class Ticket {
public int Price{ return null;} }

public class RedTicket extends Ticket {
public int Price { return 40; } }

Ticket t = new RedTicket();
int test = t.Price();
```

if I was using `virtual`/`override` keywords in C# I would expect this to return `40`. Instead it returns `null`.

How do I make it return `40`?

Comment: Your code isn't a valid code.

Comment: You've only posted a partial, hardly intelligible snippet of code for us to help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to correct the syntax for the method Price(), you forgot to use parenthesis just after the method name in both the classes.

Then you need to make the return value of Price() method in the class Ticket to an int value like 0 or 1. Because your return type is int and how can you return a null value. The code you have written won't compile.

One more thing while creating methods start the name with lowercase letter that is the standard convention following in java.

Corrected code:

```
public class Ticket {
public int price(){ return 0;} }

public class RedTicket extends Ticket {
public int price { return 40; } }

Ticket t = new RedTicket();
int test = t.Price();
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of your `Price()` method is `int`. `null` cannot be assigned to `int` so returning `null` in the `Price()` causes an compile error. You also forgot the brackets at your `Price()` method.

The following class definition should compile:

```
public class Ticket {
    public int Price() { // added brackets
        return 1; // changed null to an int value
    } 
}

public class RedTicket extends Ticket {
    public int Price() {
        return 40; 
    }
}
```

If you now execute

```
Ticket t = new RedTicket();
int test = t.Price();
```

you will geht `40` (and not `1` which is returned by `Ticket.Price()`).

Comment: you also should follow java code conventions and not c# , methods starts with lower case

Comment: I tried to fix the code with fewest changes possible. So it is easily possible to copy the code back to the IDE without changing any other code (which might be the case if I change method names). I could have changed method names to follow conventions, added `@Override` and Javadoc comments.. but this isn't part of the question..